# "From:" field in file browser

Tags: android, android-11

I'm working with Android 11.  To save files to a shared location we use the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent.  This results in an OS provided file dialog coming up with the application having permission to write to the selected file as expected.  This all works fine.

What I am looking for additional information on is the information that gets associated with a file.  When using the file browser on the device the usual fields are shown such as file name, date created, size, but there is also a from field.  For the files saved by my application the field has values like "MTP Host" or "SecSoundPicker".  Where do these values come from?  Am I able to make my application name show up here as the source of the file?

Thanks

Comment: "but there is also a from field" -- are you sure that is part of standard Android? I am not seeing this on a Pixel 4.

Comment: @CommonsWare It could very well be a Samsung thing instead of standard Android.  I'm also only seeing it shown when viewing files using the "Downloads" shortcut in the Samsung provided file browser.